# Enable a button everyday at particular time(2 am) in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a todo list with a 'done' button with each todo. Once the 'done' button is clicked by the user, it will be disabled. The button should be enabled at 2 am everyday. 
I could disable the button, but i am unable to enable it at 2 am. Here is my code.

```
$scope.doneItem = function(todo) {
    todo.stopSpam = true; 
    $interval(callAtInterval, 3000);

    function callAtInterval(){
        var date = new Date();
        if (date.getHours() === 2 && date.getMinutes() ===0){
            todo.stopSpam = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: if you are using Apps on Different Time Zones it is Gonna be a Issue  Better use momentjs for getting time from timeZone and Play with it and Flags :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you're trying to do this with intervals, I'm going to assume you're going to be leaving the page with your app up. What you do in your example *technically* can work, but only if the interval falls exactly on 2 AM (ignoring seconds and milliseconds). The easiest accurate way I can think of is to just do a quick calculation of the interval between "now" and 2 AM.

```
var date = new Date(); //This gets the current date and time
var timeInterval = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()+1,2)-date;
//This gets the difference between the time and 2 AM the next day.

//Now you can make an accurate interval call
$interval(callAtInterval, timeInterval);
```

This way will limit it to 2:00 AM *the next day*. If, however, for 1 AM you didn't want to skip that day's 2 AM to enable it, you'd make one more quick check.

```
var timeInterval;
if(date.getHours()>2)
    timeInterval = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(),2)-date;
else
    timeInterval = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()+1,2)-date;
```